# Page getting refreshed even after calling ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

```
<section class="owner-sec sec1">
    <section class="owner-txt">
        <div class="first-name">  <?php echo $first_name ?></div>
        <div class="last-name">  <?php echo $last_name ?></div>
    </section>
    <section class="bttn-save-owner bttn-save-owner1" style="display:none" > 
        <button id="savebtn1" onclick ="saveValue($(this),this.id)" class="save-bttn">Save Changes </button> 
    </section>
</section>
```

////////////////////////////////////////

Javascript code

```
function saveValue(target,id){ 
    var userId = <?php echo $user_id ?>;
    var bttnId = id.split('savebtn');   
    if(bttnId[1]==1){
        var bttnId=1;
        var firstName =   $('.first-name').text();
        var lastName =   $('.last-name').text();
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "<?php echo $this->webroot;?>update.php",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'firstName':  firstName,
                'lastName': lastName,
                'userId': userId,
                'bttnId':bttnId
            },
            success: function (data) { }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can I see the rest of your html?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `return false;` at the end of `saveValue()` method:

```
function saveValue(target,id){
    var userId = <?php echo $user_id ?>;
    var bttnId = id.split('savebtn');
    if(bttnId[1]==1) {
        var bttnId=1;
        var firstName =   $('.first-name').text();
        var lastName =   $('.last-name').text();
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "<?php echo $this->webroot;?>update.php",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'firstName':  firstName,
                'lastName': lastName,
                'userId': userId,
                'bttnId':bttnId
            },
            success: function (data) { }
        });
    }
    return false;
} // also you need a } here. it's missing from your code
```

**More description:** The `button` element's default `type` is so confusing in different browsers. But in most, it has a `submit` value. Also, in your code, you didn't set the `type` attribute. So, it will have `type="submit"` (by default) in most browsers and when you click on it, it will post the form, unless someway you prevent that. Well, returning a `false` at the end of calling method will do that.

Another way is to specifying the `type` value for the `button`:

```
<button type=""button"  id="savebtn1" onclick="saveValue($(this),this.id)" class="save-bttn">Save Changes </button>
```

**UPDATE:** About `event.preventDefault();`

Yep, you can use this. But I personally will not recommend that in form submission. Sometimes it just not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid `onclick="..."` because it's harder to maintain and can lead to mistake.
Instead add a listener on the click event and stop the default action (submit the form)

```
document.getElementById("savebtn1").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // do other stuff
});
```

Or if you are using jQuery (and seems like you are)

```
$('#savebtn1').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // do other stuff
});
```